# Can I use Mac Studio to play fancy PC games?

Tags: macos, mac, windows, games

Given a high-end Mac Studio, is it possible to play 'big' PC games? What is the appropriate way *as of now* (October 2023)?

I've heard of Boot Camp long ago, but that doesn't sound neat to me.
I used to have some experience with Virtualbox or so. I wonder why don't we just install Windows and games on virtual machines if we have a lot of resources on the host Mac. Does this make sense at all or there are way better options?

Comment: “Bootcamp doesn’t sound *neat*? That’s an odd metric to evaluate a technology.  However, it is *moot*. The Studio machines run only Silicon, no intel so it’s pointless to go down this path.

Comment: Could add in some expectations? What do you class as a 'big' game that you'd expect to be able to play on AS? Some more focus might bring a more specific answer than mine.

Answer (score 3):

An extremely comprehensive resource dedicated to gaming on Apple Silicon can be found at [AppleGamingWiki](https://www.applegamingwiki.com/wiki/Home)

It lists quite a lot of games and evaluates their performance (or otherwise) for various different methods of execution: Native, Rosetta2 translation, Wine / Crossover etc.

From personal experience using Steam I have Baldur's Gate 3, Eve Online, Stellaris, EU4, and a few others, all running perfectly with high graphics settings on an M1 Pro MBP.

Quietly as well, I'd suspect the same couldn't be said for a lot of the old Intel hardware. There are a number of architectural advantages in the Apple Silicon unified memory scheme re. graphics. As the same memory is accessible by CPU and GPU (not the same as a GPU reserving a chunk of system RAM as in an Intel integrated graphics chipset), the system spends less time copying between the two's respective memory, as it would in an Intel system.

The list is not as restrictive as you might think. However the developer must put some minimum effort in, but the situation is improving. Don't expect to be playing any CoD  at reasonable performance though.

Sonoma Game Mode (Apple Silicon only) also improves the responsiveness of games, giving more priority. Some [words of wisdom](https://eclecticlight.co/2023/10/17/what-does-game-mode-do/) from Howard Oakley re. Game Mode.

Answer (score 1):

The Mac Studio has only ever been released with Apple Silicon chips. These machines will not run the older Boot Camp, which allowed a separate installation of Windows to be run on an Intel-based Mac. Only Windows on ARM can be run on this machine, and it is very limited, likely not supporting 'big' games. In addition, the Apple Silicon Macs do not provide or support for standalone video cards, and therefore may not provide the video performance a dedicated video card (along with its power consumption) can support.

If you must have a Mac for this purpose, your best bet is to find an Intel Mac Mini, or perhaps a used Intel based Mac Pro to support the highest performance. Or simply get a cheap windows PC dedicated to gaming.

Answer (score 1):

While they’re not *very* demanding games, Civilization VI and Kerbal Space Program both run well in a Parallels VM running ARM Windows 10 on my M2 MacBook Air.

Comment: The macOS Steam version of KSP (intel) also runs fine with Rosetta 2. No need for the virtualisation if you don't need it for anything else.